# How to use XML attributes, instead of element tags to build a database with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Brief:

- I have a native binary file(s) that has been converted to an XML file.
- I have been tasked with creating a way to provide access to the data within these XML files as simply as possible (due to my lack of programming knowledge!)
- I have thought, that I will create a HTML webpage with an IFRAME linking to the repository where these XML files are kept, this webpage can then be linked to from our internal Intranet.
- This would then open up the desired XML file - in the Browser - formatted like a spreadsheet with all relevant information showing.
- Therefore, everybody within the company who has access to our network via their provided devices will be able to get to these files should they need be
- I'm an apprentice in post for only about 4 months now, and this is a task that has been floating around for years, but everybody has bigger fish to fry! So this is a nice learning curve (albeit steep) for me to find my place in the team :)

UPDATE #2

Apologies for deleting everything I have written prior. For original code snippets, please see Daniel's answer. I feel I am now able to articulate my question now I have a better undertanding and have made some progress...

- I am using XLS Version 1.0. I will test out with 2.0 tomorrow perhaps, but as I know 1.0 works, I have only been working with that 1.0. (As I am hotspotting on my personal laptop, it has taken me a while to copy line-for-line Daniel's help with this onto my Work Computer, which are all offline for security reasons).
- I have noticed my original code should be better reflective of my source code, so please see below for my sample dataset XML. The difficulty I am having is that for obvious reasons I can't just copy in my original dataset. It is also a large file (and there are thousands of these same types of files, all ~900 lines & ~80,000 chars) - [I am finding this helpful for my development having to retype everything and change element names etc though!]

`

```
  <unit typeNo="2" typeName="Digital" name="Digital Board" index="1" addr="10">
    <analogue>
    </analogue>
    <digital>
      <PNT point="1" description="something" number="8000" />
      <PNT point="2" description="something else" number="9000" />
    </digital>
    <control>
    </control>
  </unit>

  <unit typeNo="3" typeName="Control" name="Control Board" index="6" addr="15">
    <analogue>
    </analogue>
    <digital>
    </digital>
    <control>
      <PNT point="1" description="something" number="5000" />
      <PNT point="2" description="something else" number="5050" />
    </control>
  </unit>
</devices>`
```

@Daniel-Haley so far, so good, thank you for your input! I have used your method **all attributes are known** as I do know them! I know have EVERYTHING displayed in the browser, displayed as text, not code, so that's a huge step in the right direction.

Now, as you will notice differing from my OP, each unit has either Analogue, Digital or Control boards. These are assigned a value based on it's function in the field. Our engineers will use this data to update configurations based on this database of XML files (so effectivly this is a DB of every unit's current configuration) for reference, backup and programming replacement units.

- After trawling my original data, I have noticed that under each `<UNIT>` there are `<Digital> , <Analogue>, <Control>` sub-elements. These are only populated if the unit type matches. I think there is a lot of uniformity due to the huge amount of data working with
- When the XML files are displayed with the stylesheet, the redundant fields are visible, adding bulk and making the output very busy. I would now like to omit any blank fields that aren't relevant
- I would also like to make a Key where I can assign `<typeNo>` values that can then reflect in the output, so the source file being e.g `<typeNo="1">` equivalent to Digital perhaps, and in a table heading, the XLS can look up the Key, and display the type based on that value
- There are also redundant attributes in the `<unit>` tags that don't need to be displayed in the output.

Thank you everybody for your help so far, and thank you in advance also!

Apologies for my rambling long description. I hope I have made this clear what I am aiming to achieve, and having little understanding of this, makes it difficult for me to articulate what I'm trying to do, and without being able to just copy all the source over, I am slowly growing in my knowledge of this, bear with me :D

Comment: Please share the desired output structure so as to understand which attributes are to be used for extracting values.

Comment: Hi Aniket, thank you for the feedback, I have added a quick screenshot of the desired output, as you can see it is basically a table that has the information mapped across it. I have also added "Point" into the code, as this is actually important (apologies for missing it out before!)

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using/able to use?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! Have been off for weeks, I am using version 1.0, just back in the office now and will try to go through everything and catch up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a new row for each `ANG`, so you'd have to change this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="devices/peripheral/analog">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ANG/@point"></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ANG/@something"></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ANG/@anything"></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="devices/peripheral/analog/ANG">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@point"></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@something"></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@anything"></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

this is assuming that you know all the attributes.

If all the attributes are known, this is how I'd do a full example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="peripheral|internal|external">
    <div>
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(),$lower,$upper)"/></h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="unit/*"/>      
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="unit/*">    
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3">
            <xsl:value-of select="
              concat(
              translate(substring(local-name(),1,1),$lower,$upper),
              substring(local-name(),2),
              ' Board ')"/>
            <xsl:number from="peripheral|internal|external" level="any"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>point</th>
          <th>something</th>
          <th>anything</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="ANG">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@point"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@something"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@anything"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the attributes are not known, I would use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)/[xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) to create a unique list of attribute names for the `ANG` children of each `analog`|`digital`.

I'd use that list to determine the number of columns (for colspan), popluate the header columns, and populate the columns for each row (a new row for each `ANG`).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kAttrs" match="ANG/@*" 
    use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::digital|ancestor::analog),'|',local-name())"/>

  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="peripheral|internal|external">
    <div>
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(),$lower,$upper)"/></h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="unit/*"/>      
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="unit/*">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
    <!--
      String containing a unique list of attributes from ANG children
      (separated by |). 
      Used to guarantee that each row has the right value in each column.
      Example value: point|something|anything|
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="attrs">
      <xsl:for-each select="ANG/@*[count(.|
        key('kAttrs',concat($id,'|',local-name()))[1]
        )=1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'|')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="colspan" 
      select="string-length($attrs) - string-length(translate($attrs,'|',''))"/>
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> $attrs: <xsl:value-of select="$attrs"/></xsl:message>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="{$colspan}">
            <xsl:value-of select="
              concat(
              translate(substring(local-name(),1,1),$lower,$upper),
              substring(local-name(),2),
              ' Board ')"/>
            <xsl:number from="peripheral|internal|external" level="any"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!--Recursive template call to get the attribute names.-->
          <xsl:call-template name="getVal">
            <xsl:with-param name="attrs" select="$attrs"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'head'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--Each ANG is a new row.-->
        <xsl:for-each select="ANG">
          <tr>
            <!--Recursive template call to get the attribute values.-->
            <xsl:call-template name="getVal">
              <xsl:with-param name="attrs" select="$attrs"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'body'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getVal">
    <xsl:param name="attrs"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentAttr" select="substring-before($attrs,'|')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remainingAttrs" select="substring-after($attrs,'|')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$type = 'head'">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="$currentAttr"/></th>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$type = 'body'">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name()=$currentAttr]"/></td>        
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--This is what makes the template recursive.-->
    <xsl:if test="$remainingAttrs">
      <xsl:call-template name="getVal">
        <xsl:with-param name="attrs" select="$remainingAttrs"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$type"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can use XSLT 2.0, it becomes a lot simpler...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="peripheral|internal|external">
    <div>
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(local-name())"/></h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="unit/*"/>      
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="unit/*">
    <!--Sequence containing a unique list of attributes from ANG children. 
      Used to guarantee that each row has the right value in each column.-->
    <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="distinct-values(ANG/@*/local-name())"/>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="{count($attrs)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="
              concat(
              upper-case(substring(local-name(),1,1)),
              substring(local-name(),2),
              ' Board ')"/>
            <xsl:number from="peripheral|internal|external" level="any"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
            <th>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </th>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="ANG">
          <xsl:variable name="current" select="current()"/>
          <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current/@*[local-name()=current()]"/>
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All three of the above stylesheets, using this input:

```
<devices>
    <peripheral>
        <unit type="1" name="foo" version="1" index="01A" address="02B" parentType="1" parentIndex="9">
            <analog>
                <ANG point="1" something="foo" anything="bar" />
                <ANG point="2" something="oof" anything="rab" />
            </analog>
            <digital>
                <ANG point="1" something="foo" anything="bar" />
                <ANG point="2" something="oof" anything="rab" />
            </digital>
        </unit>
    </peripheral>
    <internal>
        <unit type="2" name="foobar" version="2" index="90Z" address="50X" parentType="7" parentIndex="5">
            <analog>
                <ANG point="1" something="foo" anything="bar" />
                <ANG point="2" something="oof" anything="rab" />
            </analog>
            <digital>
                <ANG point="1" something="foo" anything="bar" />
                <ANG point="2" something="oof" anything="rab" />
            </digital>
        </unit>
    </internal>   
</devices>
```

will produce the following output...

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h1>PERIPHERAL</h1>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Analog Board 1</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th>point</th>
                  <th>something</th>
                  <th>anything</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>foo</td>
                  <td>bar</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>oof</td>
                  <td>rab</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Digital Board 1</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th>point</th>
                  <th>something</th>
                  <th>anything</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>foo</td>
                  <td>bar</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>oof</td>
                  <td>rab</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div>
         <h1>INTERNAL</h1>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Analog Board 1</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th>point</th>
                  <th>something</th>
                  <th>anything</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>foo</td>
                  <td>bar</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>oof</td>
                  <td>rab</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Digital Board 1</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th>point</th>
                  <th>something</th>
                  <th>anything</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>foo</td>
                  <td>bar</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>oof</td>
                  <td>rab</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

To see how the second two stylesheets would handle different input, start adding new attributes to the `ANG` elements.

Comment: Happy New Year! Thank you for such a comprehensive response - i'll go through this and let you know where I have got to with your answer! Cheers Daniel, keep you posted! :)

Comment: Hey @daniel-haley , First off, I want to thank you again for your input. Having just gone through everything you've told me, and copied your code across and made a few edits to fit my source I am very appreciative of what work you have put into helping me :)

Working through this has helped me understand a lot more about this language and I am certainly many steps closer to my end result! 

I now have further questions (as I imagine the more I work through, the more questions I'll end up with!) - which I'll update the OP to where I am at now!